# how to modify order/items.phtml file in magento 2

Tags: magento2

1. I copied file from Following Location:

vendor\magento\module_sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml
and paste in

```
app\code\vendorname\Madule\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml
```

2.Copied   sales_order_view.xml from

`vendor\magento\module_sales\view\frontend\layout` and paste it in custom module

at

```
app\code\vendorname\Madule\view\frontend\layout
```

did changes in template path

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" name="order_items" template="vendorname_Madule::order/items.phtml">
```

still it show vendor files

Comment: Post the code to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage this from a custom module then

Create below layout files at

1. **app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{Vendorname}_{Modulename}::order/items.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. **app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/view/frontend/layout/sales_guest_print.xml**

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{Vendorname}_{Modulename}::order/items.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. **app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/view/frontend/layout/sales_guest_view.xml**

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{Vendorname}_{Modulename}::order/items.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

4. **app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print.xml**

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{Vendorname}_{Modulename}::order/items.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You Module should be depend on **Magento_Sales** modules,So add  **Magento_Sales** as depends module of your module using **module.xml**`(app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/)`

### By Theme

If you using any custom theme then just copy

```
vendor\magento\module_sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml
```

**to**

```
app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendorname}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items.phtml
```

And

```
vendor\magento\module_sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_view.xml
```

**to**

```
app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendorname}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```

Comment: i want to do with custom module

Comment: but whenever  add another block , all overrided block run well.. but my new block is still same e.g <Block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">                 <arguments>
                            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="5" class="mark"</argument><argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument></arguments><block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml"/></Block> , change only colspan 4 to 5