# How to override template Magento_Sales::order/items.phtml in custom module?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I have to override `Magento_Sales::order/items.phtml` frontend template in custom module. I have added below code to `sales_order_view.xml` file of my module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/items.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

It throws below exception

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'arguments': This element is not expected.

How I can override mentioned phtml file ? I have followed [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236796/9169) but it throws same exception.

**Edit:** As [action node is deprecated](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html), I do not want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the below code for your **sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Alternative solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items" template="Vendor_Module::order/items.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: But action is deprecated right?

Comment: No you can use it in magento 2 as well but not like magento 1.

Comment: Here it says action node is deprecated https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act

Comment: Yes but you can still use. Which version of magento you are using? Can you try it by adding it to your code?

Comment: I am using 2.2.5 and will keep upgrading it so in future it might cause issue.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I have added alternative solution.

Comment: I have used the alternation solution but I got the following error.Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Renderer list for block "order_items" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
 <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>

    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I have seen action node is deprecated. Is there any alternative?

Comment: yes, you are right . it is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override front end template than you have to specify action method. without action Magento can't interpret what you want to override.

So try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```